# Deploy finished laravel project on localhost for Client - laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am very new to laravel and i have a finished product for a client. I want to know the steps on how to deploy this application for my client who is requesting to use the application on localhost on his computer.

I have been looking for steps to do this. Any help please?

PS: This is my first time handling such deployment in programming.

Comment: Just setup all necessary setup on his computer like web server, composer, etc. And then, copy the project and import the database. Then it will throw an error, just post it here so we can continue.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/installation basically the whole "getting started" section of the manual

Comment: Because you are that much new to laravel. I will suggest you to go ahead and use TeamViewer to demo him instead of wasting your's and his time. But, if it is absolutely necessary then you can also use git to clone it to your client's pc and installing everything the PC needs.

Comment: Use `valet share` for demos, code stays with you and you are in control, thats how I do it.

Comment: so did u find certain answer?

Answer (score 1):

Here you have documenation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/deployment
Just remember to use:

Get dependencies:

```
composer install
```

Clear cache in configuration:

```
php artisan config:cache
```

Clear route cache:

```
php artisan route:cache
```

Clear view cache:

```
php artisan view:clear
```

All those operations must be done on production server. 
If you do not know how to send files from localhost to production server - read about GIT.

Good luck!

Comment: Does it mean my code (files) will be on the clients computer ?

Comment: It means that files go from your localhost (your machine) to the server (it can be abywhere) that client has access to it by SSH or FTP

Comment: No, i mean the client can have access to my code and could even temper with it ?

Comment: If you deploy your code to his pc (which seems to be what you asked/want): Yes. Then hee has access and he can edit it any way he deems fun.

Answer (score 0):

Install all necessary components on his computer to use laravel.

1. Install Web Server (e.g. WAMP, XAMPP, MAMP).
2. Install Composer.
3. Copy the project to his computer.
4. Export the database (if any), then import it on his computer.
5. Open terminal/cmd, locate to the project folder, run: `composer update`.
6. After that, run: `composer dump-autoload`.
7. Visit it in the browser.
8. Grab some drink, and relax. That should do it.

NOTE: This is only work on local (localhost/on his computer).

Comment: That means, my client can have acccess to my code since the project code will be on his/her machine. Just like how i do have access simply

Comment: It will looks exactly what you have on your machine.

Comment: Its understandable now..perfect

Comment: Alright then. Bring it on, then get back here if it worked or if you get any error. So either you can mark it a check as the answer or add some comment. Good luck!